# What browsers support HTML 5 / CSS3

Tags: html, browser

Was reading that IE9 will support HTML 5/ CSS 3

What other browsers support this?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

See:

- [Browser support for CSS3 and HTML5](http://www.deepbluesky.com/blog/-/browser-support-for-css3-and-html5_72/)
- [When can I use...](http://caniuse.com/)

Answer (score 11):

There's an excellent graphical summary of browser support for the various features here:

http://html5readiness.com/

...which uses data from [When Can I Use...](http://caniuse.com/)

Answer (score 1):

Also There is a way to support HTML5 elements on IE8 and below using the "shiv".

You can read all about it [here](http://www.sitepoint.com/html5-older-browsers-and-the-shiv/):

But to sum it up, new HTML5 elements such a `<section>`, `<article>`, `<aside>` etc... were not a part of the original HTML4 spec which older browsers such as IE8 conform to. However there is a way for older browsers to recognize HTML5 elements using the code snippet below:

```
"abbr article aside audio bdi canvas data datalist details figcaption figure "+
"footer header hgroup main mark meter nav output progress section " +
"summary template time video"
.replace(/w+/g, function(a){ document.createElement(a) });
```

Remember to execute this immediately on page load.