# CSS3 support on browsers

Tags: css

Should I fully learn CSS3 from the W3 "CSS specifications" or is CSS3 not fully supported on browsers yet?

All in the title :)

Comment: I'm pretty sure your second part is answered in too many places to count, including within the browsers themselves.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3617200/what-browsers-support-html-5-css3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is worth to learn. Even if will take some time until all browser supports the same things most browsers gives the possibility to user browser-based properties for css3 support. IE is the biggest problem is this field, but using scripts like [css3pie](http://css3pie.com/) then you can support css3 for internet explorer also. Some good sites offer you cross browser css3 are the following:

http://css3please.com/

http://css3generator.com/

Also visit http://www.css3.info to keep in touch with all news about css3. In any case worth.

Comment: Everything I wanted and even more. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Good overview of CSS3 support among various browsers is e.g. here http://www.findmebyip.com/litmus and here http://www.deepbluesky.com/blog/-/browser-support-for-css3-and-html5_72/